# input() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python 3. I got the unhandled TypeError which is written in title, when i was trying to run the following script:

```
name = input("Give me your name: ")
print("Your name is " + name)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me, are you sure the error come from that ? Also the error you give to us is not common for inpu

Comment: The script runs with no errors.

Comment: Have you defined a function called `input`?

Comment: @jizhihao I think you're right. Python's built-in `input()` takes **0 or 1** positional arguments, not 2. Arshia, please provide a [mre]. You can [edit] the question. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].